# Perceptron definition doubts

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, definition, mathematical-statistics

I'm preparing a presentation about neural networks and I have doubts about the perceptron definition. Some sources I found in the internet tell that it's a basic artificial neuron, thus it's the basic part of a neural's network structure (and so have I written), but some say that it's the most basic neural network and not a part of it (e.g. the polish Wikipedia perceptron article, but not the english one) .
I see the second ones point, because this might happen, but my problem is: can anyone accuse me of making a mistake and that I can't say a perceptron is the basic part of a neural network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (single-layer) perceptron is a neural network on its own, but it is a neural network with a single neuron. In that case, more complex multi-layer neural networks with multiple neurons can be seen as equivalent to assembling a bunch of perceptrons together. And it is not uncommon in the literature to talk about multi-layer perceptrons as components in a larger network.

So I would introduce perceptron as a neural network instead of a part of a neural network to avoid confusion, it is frequently spoken of as part of a network instead, and there's nothing technically incorrect about it.